# GLIBC_2.28 not found in Docker image amazonlinux

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, docker

I am using docker image `amazonlinux` to build my aws-lambdas in Python. Now, I'm getting the following build error.

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found
```

It was triggered by the Python `cryptography` package. I can
do version locking `cryptography==3.4.8` to fix the problem.

However, I want to install GLIBC_2.28 into the image. How should I do it?

Comment: Which tag are you using? `amazonlinux:2` or `amazonlinux:2023` etc.?

Comment: simply amazonlinux

Comment: if you are using Debian you are all out of luck, they don't have the 2.28 in their latest release yet. Ubuntu 22.04 has it though, so that should work. Not sure what docker uses

Comment: You won't really be able to change the `glibc` version in the container without breaking it entirely. However, the build should still work as `amazonlinux` -> `amazonlinux:latest` -> `amazonlinux:2023` which has `glibc.2.34-52` support. If you can post your `Dockerfile` and the command you are using to initiate `docker build` should be able to help.